# Problem trying to bake normal map (map has no bumps/height)

Tags: texturing, normals, texture-baking, baking, normal-map

I am quite new with blender ( I know how to use a few things ), but today I was having a really  hard time trying to understand why my normal map looked a bit weird after baking the normal map. (Using both Blender 3.6.0 and 2.9.3)
To be more clear, I tried to follow a tutorial (link to that tutorial : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzBu5mLBNBs") and I tried to follow the guy and I even used an easier model (you will see the images down below), but after baking the normal map the result had some lines that were not supposed to appear. Long story short, I tried watching other tutorials about normal maps and I tried to read as many forums about normal maps baking problems (maybe I am dumb and I am missing something simple).

Here are the images :

1. Here is the object I am trying to bake:

[image: Object that I want to bake]

2.This is the baking result of the normal map :

[image: Normal map result]

3.This is how it look like, after I connect the Image texture node to the normal of the plane (the empty and straight plane)
[image: Result on empty plane]

In the end, I want to add that below I put an image with the view of the object in "Viewport Shading" where you can clearly see where those lines could have appeared (I tried to turn off the light hoping that this is how they will go), but in vain.
[image: Problem]

```
I hope to hear an answer as soon as possible !
```

Comment: It looks to me like you probably baked the normals of a flat plane to your bumpy grid, rather than vice versa.  The lines come from the triangulation of the non-planar quads in the bumpy grid, which change the tangent space along those triangles.  The "selected to active" means that the thing you want to use the normal map-- the flat plane-- should be actively selected, with a yellow outline, while the thing you want to get normals from-- the bumpy grid-- should be secondarily selected, with an orange outline.

Comment: @Nathan Thanks, that solved the problem. I felt that I was to rush in making this post, but thanks for your fast response. I hope this response will help other if they have the same problem as mine. Thanks again !!!

Comment: Note that the *Image Texture* node with the normal map image should always have the *Color Space* setting set to 'Non-Color'. In your example it is 'sRGB' and the normal map will not work properly.